# While Loop with Count Query? (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I use a while loop with a COUNT query? In the series of subqueries below, I assigned each table a static value (e.g. 'PX' AS MySite2, 'GZ' AS MySite2)...

```
 $sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
  SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GZ' AS MySite2, COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL
  ) AS X";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

To transform MySite2 into a variable ($MySite2), I simply put it inside a while loop...

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
 $MySite2 = $row['MySite2'];
}

switch($Total['num'])
{
 case 1:
```

But it isn't working. I probably just need to modify `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())`, but I haven't found the right alternative yet. The other possibility is that while loops don't work with COUNT queries. Either way, can someone tell me what the solution is?

Comment: May not fix your code, but your selects, this one for example `SELECT 'PX'` should probably be wrapped in backticks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nope, it is a scalar string.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't entirely sure. Thanks for the info @HAL9000 --- When I'm unsure, I always include the word "probably".

Comment: What do you mean by ***But it isn't working*** ? Any errors, any issues ?

Comment: Hmmm...that gives me a "column not found" error. (I assume you mean this - `PX`.) I didn't even know how to type a backtick on my keyboard; I had to copy one from the Internet. ;)

Comment: `HAL9000` corrected me by saying it was a scalar, so my comment doesn't hold water. @DavidBlomstrom

Comment: By not working, I mean the echo value doesn't echo any values at all. The page is displaying fine - but when I echo $MySite2 on the display page, nothing displays. I made a rather elaborate series of echoes, but all I see is "Hello World!" and "XYZ" (with "nada" in between...

    echo '<h3 style="color: #00f;">Hello World!</h3>';
    switch($MySite2)
    {
     case 'G1':
     echo 'G1!';
     break;
     case 'PX':
     echo 'PX!';
     break;
     default:
     echo '<b>NADA</b>';
     break; 
    }
    echo '<h3 style="color: #f00;">XYZ'.$MySite2.'</h3>';

Comment: Is your query produces any rows, when it was run directly on MySQL Server ?

Comment: Hi again David. You're only Selecting "num", so you can't expect anything else to be returned...

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Yeah... This... exactly.

Comment: From what it looks like you're trying to achieve, skip the first select query and go straight for unions. Then you can have all the rows returned in a while loop.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Post as an answer.

Comment: OK, let me see if I understand this: I originally created this series of COUNT subqueries because I thought it was the best way to display pages - and it may be, except it doesn't work so great if you want to assign static ID's to tables. Therefore, you're suggesting that I switch to a more conventional query that will do both things - display pages and give my sites static values. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what your end goal is. There are probably several solutions to whatever you're trying to achieve, and the differences in performance will most likely be negligible. Just make sure it works for you and it is easy to maintain/work with.

Comment: END GOAL: I'm basically combining several websites (each of which is divided into several sections; e.g. MySite/World, MySite2/World, MySite3/People) and merging them into one super website. So the first thing I need to do is string all the relevant tables together and do a simple query that displays a page IF the URL matches a value in one of my tables. For example, if the URL is MySite/Carl_Sagan, and Carl_Sagan is in the field URL (or a comparable field) in any one of those tables, the page displays.

Comment: However, to make it work, I also need to more or less keep track of the origins of my data. If I'm displaying data that was originally displayed at GeoWorld/People, then I'd like to give it the values MySite2 = 'GW', Section = 'People'.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think your query return the column MySite2.
try this query.

```
SELECT x.MySite2, SUM(num) as num FROM (
SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GZ' AS MySite2, COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL
) AS X group by x.MySite2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you're trying to achieve...

```
$sql = "SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS MySite2, COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GZ' AS MySite2, COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MySite2 = array();
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
 $MySite2[] = array("mysite" => $row['MySite2'], "num" => $row['num']);
}
```

You can then easily sum or otherwise calculate whatever/however you want

Comment: @ NewIn The Business - I copied and pasted your entire script as is, and I don't get any error messages. However, it returns a value for $Total of 0, rather than 1. In other words, I get a 404 error message rather than a display page.

Comment: well, I never set any $Total variable in my answer, so that is expected. You have all the data you need in $MySite2 which is an array.

Comment: Oh, I get it. With this new script, I need to scrap this: 

switch($Total['num'])
{
 case 1:

But I don't understand what I should replace it with. How do I tell my script "The page URL Carl_Sagan is in one of these tables so display this page," or "Carl_Sagan doesn't exist, so display a 404 error page?"

Comment: If there are no matches your $MySite2 array is empty. You can simply do `if ($MySite2) {//display the page } else {//Do something else}`

Comment: Now I get it; that displays the pages. But I still don't understand how to fetch my new static values. I put this switch on my display page:

 switch($row['MySite2'])
 {
  case 'G1':
  echo 'G1!';
  break;
  case 'PX':
  echo 'PX!';
  break;
  default:
  echo '<b>Nothing</b>';
  break; 
 }

But it displays "Nothing," even though the page displays OK.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom But then you can only get one row returned anyways? But with the current code you could loop through it: `foreach ($MySite2 as $array) {if ($array['mysite'] == "PX") {//Display} elseif ($array['mysite'] == "GZ") {//Display}}`

Answer (score 0):

Wow, sorry to be so dense, but it isn't completely my fault; it appears that PDO and COUNT queries just don't go well together. So until my programming skills are a little sharper, I think I need to just stick with a plain vanilla COUNT query that displays pages, then make a second "traditional" query that's designed only to give various database tables static values (website and section). Then, I can move on to more advanced tables that extract details from my DB.

Mods: I don't know if I should post this as an answer when it really isn't; it's more of a workaround. So feel free to change this from "Answer" to whatever. Or if it's easier for me to do it, let me know, and I'll delete it and post it as a comment, etc.

There are lots of great tips on this page, and I'll bookmark it as a reference. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should change "$MySite2 = $row['MySite2'];" to "$MySite2 = $row['X'];"

Since the entire query is returned as a column named 'X'.

The only other column being returned is 'num',

$row['MySite2'] will not yield a value since no column named 'MySite2' is returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not a "column". It is a resultset alias.

Comment: It appears that's what needs to be referenced by the $row construct.